How to approach review of sharepoint in my organization
I was looking at how best to organise the home page running on classic view. There is a staff birthday list which doesnt display properly and the feed from twitter doesnt populate data.

Too broad question. At least start with what kind of SharePoint you are using - online or on-prem. Nevertheless, such request is not appropriate for inexperienced/junior developer(?) and requires deep understanding of platform and connected services.
In your case - try to clarify expected results. Like, improvements in what areas - reduce data usage, speed up custom component performance, reduce unnecessary business actions, etc. Then work from that end.

Thanks for your response. We use SharePoint online. Any of the areas you pointed would be ok by me once  its straight forward to do.
